# Reusable types in Typescript and generic types?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm quite new to typescript and can't quite wrap my head around generic types.
I have this little code here and was wondering if there was a way to create a generic type to save me from writing  `.. | undefined` every time?

Something in the lines of `type withUndefined = ...here goes what?`

[image: Sample code]

Comment: Perhaps something like `type Maybe<T> = T | undefined`, *however* in the screenshot you've posted, there is no need for the `| undefined` at all, the optional modifier `?` on the argument name has the same effect.

Comment: @CRice So if I understand correctly it should relate to `type withUndefined<T> = T | undefined;

function logout(options: withUndefined<LogoutOptions>) ...`

but then again what are the `<fairy dust goes here>`, shown in the official docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), inserted after the function name

Comment: Those are function generic parameters

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Not applicable in my case I suppose?

Comment: I don't think so, no. They are used when you want a function to work with different types

Comment: @CRice Well thanks very much guys! Gave it a bit of a further read and I think it's starting to click. Will need to put it to practice to get the proper hang of it. If any of you wants to post it as an answer and I'll mark tick it off :)